# `overflow-x: hidden` disables navbar in Boostrap - why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I use Bootstrap v.3.2 in my responsive web app, but since the Bootstrap automatically shows the redundant horizontal space and makes the web layout look awful as well as display the horizontal scrolling bar ([see this link in Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10711)), I want to remove the redundant space in Bootstrap.

However, when I tried to write `overflow-x: hidden` to `*` as suggested in the linked issue, the layout looks good and it doesn't show the horizontal scrolling bar, but then the navbar's dropdown menu doesn't work at all (cannot be enclosed - other navbar (no dropdown link) works as usual). Why does the navbar's dropdown not work after I set `overflow-x: hidden` to `*`?

Also, when I tried to change `overflow-x: hidden` from `*` to `body`, then the navbar works properly but the layout doesn't change at all. Why?

Note that when I add `overflow-x: hidden` to `.container-fluid`, then the navbar doesn't work either as it was when written in `*`.

And finally, how can I remove the redundant horizontal space and the horizontal scrolling bar? That is what I wanted to do in the first place, so I don't mind whether I use `overflow-x` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the issue, the correct fix is to just use `container-fluid`. No need to mess with `overflow-x` yourself.

Comment: Then if my structure is something like `<header><nav></nav></header> <div class="container-fluid">{{contents}}</div> <footer></footer>`, should I include every element within the outer `<div>`? Or should I define three `<div class="container-fluid">` and put header, footer, and main contents to the respective `container-fluid`?

Comment: I'm not sure it matters either way. It's easy to check via experiment though.

Comment: Using `container-fluid` didn't work, but adding `padding-left: 0px` and `padding-right: 0px` to `.container-fluid` and `margin: 0px` to `.row` made it work properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

because if you use `*` as selector, then you'll apply the styles to EVERYTHING. You can use `*` in descendant order of an element, or if you want to apply it to everything (just the asterisk alone equals everything), then add `overflow:auto` to any element where you need scroll bars, eg your navbar